# If I use SQLAlchemy ORM, does that mean I stop querying the backend DB directly?

Tags: sql, database, orm, sqlalchemy

If I use SQLAlchemy's ORM to create objects and store them, does that mean I pretty much also only retrieve the data from the DB via SQLAlchemy? Will the underlying tables created by SQLAlchemy ORM still be sane? Can I still query the DB directly and have useful findings?

Answer (score 2):

The ORM will only create and modify the database records as they're defined. You'll be able to query them just as you normally would. Using SqlAlchemy does not limit your normal database access in any way. SqlAlchemy can output the queries used into log files for seeing what exactly they're doing. It's nothing like html generation where you then don't want to look at the html it created.